# Why does Skype continue to freeze when launching?

Tags: windows-8, skype

This began happening when I upgraded from Windows 7 to 8. Upon launching Skype, sometimes the interface just freezes and is shown as "not responding" on its own after a few seconds, then sometimes it occurs after I click on the interface. I have to end the task then relaunch.

Sometimes this same thing will occur 5-10 times in a row until eventually I get lucky and it runs fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you running the metro app? or the desktop app?